# Would this be the place to ask about (speculative) onomastics?

Tags: discussion

I've got a question about Old Norse onomastics, specifically how I could make a name that's typically masculine into a feminine one (and potentially vice-versa). Would linguistics.SE be the place to ask this kind of question, or is there another SE that I would want to take that to?

Comment: I guess it's on topic, but that doesn't mean that anyone here is qualified to answer. You may have to wait a long time.

Comment: @curiousdannii That's quite all right. I'm happy to do research on the topic on my own as well, but more eyes on the question would definitely help, since I don't have infinite time to look myself.

Comment: Still waiting for you to post that question, I'm looking forward to having a look at it.

Comment: @MaxP Sorry about that! It's a busy week. I'll post it today and let people go for it.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, certainly. Go ahead and ask.